# Show that $d(x,y)=|x-2y|$ defines a metric on $\mathbb R$

Tags: metric-spaces

Normally I can solve these problems but THIS one irritates me.

$d(x,y)=|x-2y|$ on the real numbers.

I use the axioms (from my course where I'm a student, see Image: http://puu.sh/BfjWu/7f75958f49.png).

M1: $d(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow x=y$

M2: $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ (symmetry)

M3: $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ (triangle inequality)

So can anyone tell me why M2 is wrong? I know M1 fails because we can let $x=1$ and $y=1$ then $1\neq 2$

I know M3 fails because I can let $x=5,z=2,y=1$ then 
$d(5,1)=|5-2\cdot 1|=3>1+0=|5-2\cdot 2|+|2-2\cdot 1|=d(5,2)+d(2,1)$

But I can't figure out why M2 fails... First I tried this:

$d(x,y)=|x-2y|=|2y-x|=d(y,x)$

Then M2 holds, but I think it's wrong. In the other hand, I see M2 fails if:

$d(x,y)=|x-2y| \neq |y-2x|=d(y,x)$

Can anyone help me to clear it up?

Comment: Try $x = 1$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: Yea, but let x=1 and y=2 then |1-2*2|=|2*2-1| which gives me |-3|=3 and the numerical of -3 is 3, hence 3=3

Edit: If i let x=1 and y=0, then I will end up with |1-2*0|=|2*0-1| which is also gives me 1=1.

Comment: Btw I use my idea that:
$d(x,y)=|x-2y|=|2y-x|=d(y,x)$ but do I really have to use $d(x,y)=|x-2y|=|y-2x|=d(y,x)$ because x and y have swapped places but not the constant 2. If I should use the last one I typed, then I see M2 fails.

Comment: $|x-2y| = |-(2y-x)| = |2y-x|$

Comment: @KasperMedK Your calculation is wrong. If we let $x=1$ and $y=0$, then $\lvert x-2y \rvert =1$, and $\lvert y-2x \rvert = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah! Your last argument is the correct one.

You have to show that 
           |x-2y|=|y-2x|.

Which obviously fails because x=1 &y=0 as given in comments does not satisfy it